# Try/catch I don't seem to know where to put it

Tags: java

```
 Story.direct3();
            br.readLine();
            Story.des();
            try{
            short choice1 = Short.parseShort(br.readLine());

            switch(choice1){
                case 1:
                    Display.yes();
                    br.readLine();
                    Story.rid();
                    String answ = br.readLine();

                    if ("Gravity".equals(answ) || "gravity".equals(answ)){
                        Display.correct();
                        Short choice2 = Short.parseShort(br.readLine());

                        switch(choice2){
                            case 1:

                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        int less = player.hp - 10;
                        System.out.println("Wrong answer! Your hp will be lessen by 10. The correct answer is : 'Gravity'");
                        System.out.println("Your remaining HP is: " + less + "[press enter to continue...]");
                        br.readLine();
                        Story.wrong();
                        br.readLine();

                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Story.wrong1();
                    br.readLine();
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                System.out.println("Would you like to change your battle item?"
            + "\n[1] Yes"
             + "\n[2] No");
            }
```

I just started coding java past 2 month and asked for my friends code and tried experimenting on it. The thing is I don't know how to put the try/catch. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where do you need it? What's the problem with the code now? Do explain a bit more what you're having problems with.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen When I type the wrong answer the player should be able to equip a battle item. That's where the "Would you like to change your battle item?" comes out. How should i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to exception handling you should put only line/block of code that can cause some exception inside try-catch block. For example in your case you could have try-catch for user input to make sure that he provided integer number:

```
try{
        short choice1 = Short.parseShort(br.readLine());
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("Would you like to change your battle item?"
        + "\n[1] Yes"
         + "\n[2] No");
}
```

But this will only check if his input is number, what if he write down 3 or 4 which your switch doesn't handle? You should include either default case for switch or check if number is bigger than 2 or smaller than 1 and repeat question.

Also this type of input could be handled much easier without relying on error handling:

```
String s = br.readLine();
while(!s.equals("2") || s.equals("1")){
    System.out.println("Invalid input, try again:");// change message to fit your game
    s = br.readLine();
}
if(s.equals("1")){
    //Do something
}else{
    //Do something
}
```

Remember that you should try to avoid using try-catch if it is possible to do it without making code too complex. And in this case you end up with much simpler code.